# Unexpected results from R's gsub function

Tags: r

`gsub` doesn't seem to be working as expected for me.

My data is a character vector which has a lot of values with countries' names in this format: `"count(Country_Desc).Afghanistan"`. The full data can be found here:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1fa2d94b21a684139ffa

I was going to use `gsub` to leave only the actual countries' names for the elements in that format:

```
gsub("count(Country_Desc).", "", nms)
```

To my surprise this doesn't do anything; the result is the same as the original. I tried a few variations of this but to no avail.

I notice that if, just as an experiment, I run this:

```
gsub("Western Sahara", "", nms)
```

then it removes that country's name as expected (unfortunately that's not what I need to do).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape the parentheses, or set `fixed=TRUE`. Parenthesis are used for grouping regular expressions.

```
R> gsub("count\\(Country_Desc\\).", "", nms)
R> gsub("count(Country_Desc).", "", nms, fixed=TRUE)
```

Comment: That's absolutely right, thanks! I just figured it out myself. I knew I was going to be kicking myself over this one!

Comment: I guess you should escape the period as well with `fixed=F`, though it gets the job done anyway. Also, if there are no other periods in `nms`, an easier `regex` would be `gsub(".*\\.","",nms)`